# How to calculate size of a VERY large folder over FTP?

Tags: linux, ftp, disk-utility

I have FTP access to a web-server which has a large folder (By large I mean ~200GB).
How can I get number of files and it's exact size?
I have tried 'du -hs' but it takes a life to receive a response and meanwhile my connection drops and everything is ruined.

Is there a more quick/stable way to do this?

P.S. Remote OS is linux

Comment: How are you running `du -hs`? SSH?

Comment: no I used 'lftp'. I don't know if its supported in original ftp command